# Using TestNG notations like @parameters or @dataprovider... every time it skips the method

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

Everytime it skip the method when I use TESTNG annotations @dataprovider or @Parameters. My code is mentioned below. 
    enter code here

```
               package crossbrowser;

               import org.openqa.selenium.By;
                import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
                import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
                  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

          public class CrossTest 
 {

WebDriver driver;

@Test
@Parameters("browser")  
public void crosstest1(String BrowserName)
{
 if(BrowserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox"))
{
  driver=new FirefoxDriver();   

 }

String baseUrl = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
 driver.get(baseUrl);
 System.out.print("hello")

}


 }
```

Every I time run this code I get this error

```
SKIPPED: crosstest1
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'browser' is required by @Test on method crosstest1 but has not  been marked @Optional or defined
```

Same problem is with @DataProvider also.

XML file for the above code is

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="Suite">
   <test name="Test">
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
  <classes>
    <class name="crossbrowser.CrossTest"/>


    </classes>




   </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

On seeing the pasted XML file below closing tag written twice

```
  </test>
```

if it not pasting problem then it should be issue in testng.xml file so update it correctly.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Its a pasting mistake.. Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Your xml file to use with @parameters should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="1">
 <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
        <class name="crossbrowser.CrossTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

In your xml you're targeting wrong class, also you shouldn't run the code but xml config file.

In your code parameter name must match with parameters in method:

```
@Test
@Parameters("BrowserName")  
public void crosstest1(String BrowserName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up before you hit the problem. You can not pass parameters into data providers from the xml file like you do @test. You will need to something like the following.

```
 public String myTestDataProvider(ITestContext context) throws Exception{
            String browser = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("browser");
            //Do Something
            return browser;
}
```

Comment: Method public java.lang.String crossbrowser.CrossTest.myTestDataProvider(org.testng.ITestContext) throws java.lang.Exception has a @Test annotation but also a return value: ignoring it. Use <suite allow-return-values="true"> to fix this

Comment: @ArohaTech Can you update your code to what you now have?  My example was just a rough guideline.